# C# Recursive delete nodes

Tags: c#, list, hierarchy

I created a class for hierarchical data. From this class I generate custom treeview. Before sending data to treeview I need delete a branch that does not end with instance with HaveData = true

```
    public class Data
    {
        public List<Data> Children
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool HaveData
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Treeview before:

```
1 First
1.1 Item
1.1.1 Item (HaveData = false)
1.2 Item
1.2.1 Item (HaveData = true)
...
```

I need:

```
1 First
1.2 Item
1.2.1 Item (HaveData = true)
...
```

How to go through all nodes and remove only those that ending HaveData = false?
Thank you.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (showing your inputs and expected outputs based on those inputs).

Comment: do you only want to delete "leafs" or "branches" to? (only 3-digit-positions or 1 and 2-digit positions too)

Comment: What if Item 1.1 has data? Do you still want to delete it? What if it had two direct children, one with data and one without data?

Comment: If item 1.1 has data = dont remove. If node has two children, delete only one, with HasData=false

Comment: nozzleman: remove only 1.1 abd 1.1.1. First node constains node 1.2 witch have data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one recursive way to do it:

```
public void DeleteBranchWithNoData()
{
    var toBeRemoved = new List<Data>();
    foreach(var child in Children)
    {
        if(!child.HaveData && (child.Children == null || !child.Children.Any()))
        {
            toBeRemoved.Add(child);
        }
        else
        {
            child.DeleteBranchWithNoData();
        }   
    }
    Children.RemoveAll(d => toBeRemoved.Contains(d));
}
```

Call this method from the top node of the branch you want to delete.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/BBBM69286)

Answer (score -3):

1. Make HaveData be true if the element has data OR any of its children have data.
2. Delete any nodes within the tree where HaveData is false.
3. ???
4. Profit.

Comment: Loaded data I get from another software. I cannot set HaveData=true for parents. This is set only at last element.