# When Not every query works with my Click event

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

My "problem" table contains categories that are used in a treeview.

The categories are listed in a hierarchical view as in this example

```
* Test 1
    * Test 2
    * Test 3
        * Test 4
        * Test 5
    * Test 6
```

This is stored in the table as

| category_Id | category_Descrepription | category_Fullpath | category_ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | Test 1 |  |
| 2 | Test 2 | Test 1\Test2 | 1 |
| 3 | Test 3 | Test 1\Test3 | 1 |
| 4 | Test 4 | Test 1\Test3\Test 4 | 3 |
| 5 | Test 5 | Test 1\Test3\Test 4 | 3 |
| 6 | Test 6 | Test 1\Test6 | 1 |

I want to be able to delete Category 3 and all its children so I use
DELETE FROM categories WHERE category_Fullpath LIKE '%Test1\\Test 3%';

In MySQL (WorkBench and HeidiSQL this works as expected, but if I use my click event that works when I pass the record ID, but it seems to do nothing when I pass the above query.

I checked the output and it produces the correct query, I even copy pasted it and executed it in KeidiSQL and it works, so why not when executed from the code.

My Button_Click event is:

```
private void ButtonDeleteCategorie(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Database dbConnection = new Database();
    dbConnection.Connect();

    int ID = int.Parse(valueId.Text);
    dbConnection.SqlCommand = "DELETE FROM ";
    // This works: dbConnection.SqlCommandString = " WHERE category_Id = " + ID + ";";
    dbConnection.SqlCommandString = " WHERE category_Fullpath LIKE '%" + valueFullpath.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + dialogCategory.diaLogCategoryValue + "%';";
    dbConnection.TableName = DatabaseTable;
    dbConnection.UpdateMySqlDataRecord();
    _ = dbConnection.LoadMySqlData();
}
```

My FUnction in my database class

```
public int UpdateMySqlDataRecord()
{

    MySqlCommand SqlCmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand
    {
        Connection = Database.myConnection,
        CommandText = SqlCommand + Connection_Query.database + "." + TableName + SqlCommandString
    };

    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connection_Query.connectionString);

    myConnection.Open();

    SqlCmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    long ID = SqlCmdUpdate.LastInsertedId;

    myConnection.Close();

    return (int)ID;
}
```

Can anyone give my a clue where i miss something

Comment: What is this class `Database` where does it come from? And why are you not using parameterized queries?

Comment: I think recursive function is the best of solutions in this matter. Use it and delete all Children.

Comment: Why is your data stored as `Test 1\Test3` and the query shows `LIKE '%Test1\\Test 3%';`? (It has an extra space before the '3' !)

Comment: @charlieface, I created the database class in the same namespace as the application.
I am calling the click event from a button on WPF page. 

I removed the parameters because I was not sure that perhaps that was causing my problem. I will put them in place when it works again.

Comment: @AtabaiFekri You mean get the Id's of the main category and its children and iterate through that list to delete the categories one by one?

Comment: Is `MySqlCommand SqlCmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand{}` the correct syntax?? Been a long time since I C#'d

Comment: @Luuk The missing spaces as typo's in this post. I So read Test1\Test3 or Test 1\Test 3 Because i can use spaces in my categories.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: yes, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init

Comment: No, Not at all. Check the link please : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49531614/5871154

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would say it is the correct syntax, it works also on other functions (adding and renaming records) although that does not always mean it is correct ;-) sometimes it is correct enough to let it work, but in this case, It is the correct syntax.

Comment: `Connection = Database.myConnection,` This doesn't make sense as you are not opening that connection, you use a different one on the next line. You need to flip it round: create the connection, add it to a new command, then open it. And you should use `using` on your connection and command objects

Comment: Not sure what the point of `Replace("\\", "\\\\")` is, can't work out why you would need it

Comment: @charlieface If I pass Test1\\Test2 t o SQL my backslashes are stripped, the i read in other posts that you have to passe 4 backslasches instead of two.

Comment: Not aware of that being the case. Even if it is true, **this is why you use parameters**, keep your code and data far away from each other

Comment: @Charlieface You are right my connection = Database.MyConnection does not make sense I removed it, and I will put the parameters back in place because that is not the reason why I don't work. I don't know how to use sing for the connection, I only know using for adding other namespaces, but how can I use this for establishing a connection to the database table?

Comment: @AtabaiFekri thank you for that link, another approach, where I did not think of, could be the key to be able to delete my categories.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553377/14868997 although that is for SQL Server the `using` syntax is the same

Answer (score 1):

with the help of @kazi-mohammad-ali-nur I found the error in my code.

Origianly I added extra backslahes to my string because in my Fullpath
`dbConnection.SqlCommandString = " WHERE category_Fullpath LIKE '%" + valueFullpath.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + dialogCategory.diaLogCategoryValue + "%';";`

Some people questioned the need of 4 backslashes, but I even needed 8 backslashes to make it work.

`dbConnection.SqlCommandString = " WHERE category_Fullpath LIKE '%" + valueFullpath.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\") + dialogCategory.diaLogCategoryValue + "%';";`

Comment: Debugging is the best option. Your effort deserves a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug and check what's the value of SqlCommandString after executing below line.

```
dbConnection.SqlCommandString = " WHERE category_Fullpath LIKE '%" + valueFullpath.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + dialogCategory.diaLogCategoryValue + "%';";
```

Please also check category_fullpath for test 1 and test 2. instead of "Test 1\Test 2" it's showing "Test 1\Test2".

Comment: I debugged the result and it was displaying the expected Result, I even copied the result and executed it in HeidiSQL, and my categories were removed.

Comment: Please debug value of SqlCmdUpdate. and paste here

Comment: The result CommandText is
`DELETE FROM modelbuilder.categories WHERE category_Fullpath LIKE '%Gereedschap\\Elektrisch\\Test1%';`

These are of course the strings I use in the real categories so therefore Gereedschap and Electrisch instead of Test1 and Test2

Comment: I think I see the problem here.
In my MainWindow I replace the '\\' with '\\\\' But here two of the four backslashes are stripped already even before I pass the string to my database connection. I replaced the two backslashes in the Mainwindows to 8 instead of 4 and it works.

Comment: That’s great. Best of luck.